# How to determine if string contains arabic symbols?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, string

I need to know, If the string is in Arabic to change the layout of my html page. How do I do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With latest ruby (at least 2.0.0 I think) also `string =~ /\p{Arabic}/` will work

Comment: Works with 1.9.3 too.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use a [Unicode regular expression](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Regexp.html#M001242) (example of Unicode in a Ruby regex) to check for the presence of [Unicode Arabic characters](http://www.alanwood.net/unicode/arabic.html).

Answer (score 0):

You can try this gem 
https://github.com/peterc/whatlanguage